# Filter files in folder and display them using ng-repeat (JS, Angular)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So, I've got some folder `archives` that contains unknown number of files, I know that:

all of them got .7z extension

half starts with letters AB and other half - CD

So folder's content looks like:

AB1234567890.7z

AB2345678901.7z

CD1234567890.7z

CD2345678901.7z

etc. That is I can do something like this:

```
<a href="archives/AB1234567890.7z" download="{{fileName}}">Download</a>
```

And on click it's gonna start downloading archive with name `AB1234567890.7z`. It's okay, but obviously I can't write links like that, it must be done with `ng-repeat`. So the question is - **how to display 2 lists of links**, where *first* list would be list with links which starts with `AB` and *second* - which starts with `CD`, respectively. Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Could you share code what you have tried till the time? that will clarify your question better. Its bit confusing

Comment: @Manoj Shevate I myself dunno how to perform that - that's why I'm here - looking for tips from more experienced guys :) as I understand it may be done like `$scope.firstList = files.filter((file) => file.substring(0, 2) === "AB"` and then `ng-repeat=‘file in firstList`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this:

```js
angular.module('app',[]).controller('test', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){  
 //$http({ method: 'GET', url: '/getNames'}).then(function(names) {
 //    $scope.files = names;
 //}) 
  $scope.files = ['AB1234567890.7z',
                  'AB2345678901.7z',
                  'CD1234567890.7z',
                  'CD2345678901.7z'];
  $scope.startWith = function(file, name){    
      return file.indexOf(name) == 0;
  }
}])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='test'>
<p>First list</p>
  <div ng-repeat='file in files' ng-if="startWith(file, 'AB')">
    <a  href='archives/{{file}}'>{{file}}</a>
  </div>      
<p>Second list</p>
  <div ng-repeat='file in files' ng-if="startWith(file, 'CD')">
    <a  href='archives/{{file}}'>{{file}}</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: looking good, but how am I supposed to announce `$scope.files` in controller?

Comment: suppose it has to be delivered by serverside from folder... I mean, list of names...

Comment: @impregnablefiend, you can use, for example, `$http` service to get names from server and then assign returned names to `$scope.files` variable, at my case.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" layout="row" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">
  <div layout="column" flex>
      <a ng-repeat="file in archivesAB" href="archives/{{file}}" download="{{file}}">{{file}}</a>
  </div>
  <div layout="column" flex>
      <a ng-repeat="file in archivesCD" href="archives/{{file}}" download="{{file}}">{{file}}</a>
  </div>
</div>

(function () {
  'use strict';
   angular
     .module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages',  'material.svgAssetsCache'])
     .controller('AppCtrl', AppCtrl);

   function AppCtrl ($scope, $log) {
     $scope.archivesAB = [
       'AB1234567890.7z',
       'AB2345678901.7z'
     ];

     $scope.archivesCD = [
       'CD1234567890.7z',
       'CD2345678901.7z'
     ];

   }
})();
```

And here is the working [codepen](http://codepen.io/sanfelice/pen/ZBEvVb)

Comment: I can't just print two collections in controller - they are unknown!... And they can change any time - like I said all I know that they lay in folder `archives` and some starts with `AB`, others - `CD`...

Comment: As far as I know you can't read files from a folder using client side javascript as AngularJS. But if you have this files in your server you could just access a URL that return that list for you.

Comment: You could use something like this:

    $timeout(function () {
        $http.get('url').success(function(response){
             $scope.archivesAB = response.archivesAB;
             $scope.archivesCD = response.archivesCD;
        });
    }, 5000);

This would access a URL that return your lists  every 5s